# Reactjs router not rendering any component

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router, react-router-dom

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: __dirname + '/src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/public',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 9999
     },
    module : {
      rules : [
        {
          test : /\.jsx?/,
          loader : 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

**src/index.js --  Try 1**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class Car extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        console.log('Inside Car Constructor');
    };
    redner(){
        return(<h1>Cars</h1>);
    }
}

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        console.log('Inside Constructor');
    };
    render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hi</h1>
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/car" Component={Car} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

render(
    <Home/>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**index.js -- Try 2**

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        console.log('Inside Constructor');
    };
    render(){
        return (<h1>Hi</h1>);
    }
}

render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
            <Route path="/car" Component={Car} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**index.js -- Try 3**

```
render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
        <Route path="/car" Component={Car} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**index.js -- Try 4**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class Car extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        console.log("Inside Car constructor");
    };

    render(){
        return (<h1>Carrssss</h1>);
    }
}

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        console.log("Inside home constructor");
    };

    render(){
        return (<h1>Hi</h1>);
    }
}

render(
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/car" component={Car} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I have tried all of the above things, but the path does not seem to work.
In the first try, **/** seems to work but not **/car**.
In the second and third try, not even the **/** is working for me.
How do I solve this error? and why is it caused?

I have tried using both the packages react-router and react-router-dom.
Tried using BrowserRouter as well instead of Router, still can't figure our anything.

Comment: What does "not seem to work" mean? Are there errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @AndyRay no there are no errors in the console. It is just not rendering the components. I get a blank page for / route and 404 for others

Comment: Without React Router, can you render your apps?

Comment: Yes, I can render just <Home /> component as well. No router nothing.
render( <Home />,  document.getElementById('container') ); 
works fine.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You have a typo there. It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I corrected the mistake and still not able to render the component. I will update the question with **Try 4** with what I am testing now.

Comment: Do not bloat yourself with so many tries. I've provided a working code. Just try it. If it does not work then it means something really weird is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not:

```
<Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
```

it is

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Notice the `component` part.

A second mistake is there is a typo in your first try. In `Car` component instead of `render` you are using `redner`.

Working code as it is:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class Car extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<h1>Cars</h1>);
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hi foo</h1>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/car" component={Car} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: Did not make any difference. I am able to get the Home path using the Try 2 file, but the Car Component. It is not even going inside the Component because there is nothing on the console even though I am logging stuff

Comment: It made a difference which is you fixed a serious problem here. Let's dig your situation a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. So what else can I check or do here?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help and taking time out to write the code as well.
I am somehow unable to run it also. It is taking ages to load the page only, still not loaded. I don't know what the issue is now. Unable to figure it out. If I find something, I'll definitely post it here.

Comment: Hey. I tried this method. If I am doing this with your code, my browser is just not rendering. It is entering the component because I log in the constructor, but not rendering. When I put the Browser Router inside ReactDOM.render() it loads but only the Home component. **/car** is still giving a 404. I don't know what has happened.

Comment: I did with create-react-app and it is working. I am not sure why, but it is working.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then, probably some config problem. Glad that you made it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that pops out to me is that you are grabbing a component called { Router }, when react-router-dom has a component called { BrowserRouter } that is often imported in this way

`import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';`

Also, you are passing a custom `history` prop to your Router. React-Router uses its history prop to determine where you are and what to render. Overriding this could be causing the issue. You can see for yourself using the React Dev Tools in your web browser. All Routed components and components wrapped with `WithRouter` will have a history prop passed down by React-Router.

Comment: You are right but there is also a `Router` component and it can be used with a custom history. It seems that problem is not that.

Comment: I believe that is just an alias of BrowserRouter and I have already tried with BrowserRouter.
And I have already tried what you mentioned above. Still no success.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation where { Router } is a valid import. [the training kit](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/MemoryRouter) has NativeRouter, MemoryRouter, and BroswerRouter, but nothing called Router to import. Perhaps the combination of both issues (invalid import and invalid case on `component`) could be the problem? I'll keep looking for anything else.

Comment: @Ronnie, here it is https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: I have edited my answer above with another observation as well.

Comment: Ah, brilliant. Now I better understand what you're doing here. Sorry to send you down the wrong path. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Yeah :) The thing is OP does not use `BrowserRouter` but instead `Router` with a custom history. But this is not the problem I think.

Comment: So, I've replicated your setup (try 4), except I used create-react-app. I copied and pasted your code into the Index.js, then changed the default `root` div to have the id `container`. There were no problems with rendering on either route. Maybe it's a webpack issue?